# Can you recommend an appropriate statistical model for predicting national blood demand?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

Can you recommend a statistical model for predicting national blood demand?

I am seeking recommendations for a statistical model to predict national blood demand. I am aware that there are several methodologies available for establishing prediction models, including regressions, time-series analysis, and machine learning.

The data I have consists of 50 years' worth of national blood usage, measured in 'Packs of RBC,' as well as 50 years' worth of national blood donation data, also described in terms of 'Packs of RBC.'

However, I am encountering a difficulty. While I believe that time-series analysis would be the most suitable statistical methodology for my purpose, there is a significant obstacle. National blood usage does not accurately represent the true 'demand' for blood. In other words, when blood donation falls significantly short of blood usage, various measures can be implemented to manage the shortage in hospitals. For instance, blood centers may supply less blood than in the previous period, and the blood management departments of hospitals may enforce stricter regulations on blood usage across all departments. As a result, a surgeon, for example, might be limited to transfusing a maximum of 8 packs of RBC instead of 10. Additionally, transfusions for patients with higher hemoglobin levels may be postponed or canceled.

Hence, the 'supply' of blood actively influences national blood usage, making it an inadequate surrogate for true 'demand' for blood. Given this situation, I am wondering if there are any statistical methods available for modeling the true 'demand' considering the interplay between the apparent 'supply' and 'demand' data.

Comment: Do you actually have data for this "true" demand? Or do you only have data for the "apparent" demand? If the latter, how would you find the "true" demand (what kind of assumptions are you willing to make)?

Comment: @user2974951 I only have data regarding the "apparent" demand, which refers to the annual blood usage categorized by the recipients' sex and age. In fact, this is precisely the question I'm interested in. I am wondering if there is a statistically robust method to estimate the "true" annual blood demand by considering the interaction between the "apparent" supply and demand data.

Comment: Statistics is not magic, it's based on data. If no data is available (for the thing you are studying) then you have to make assumptions. The model which you will use has no way of knowing what is really happening behind the curtains, the model can only predict what is observed. Is there any other data which you can use in the model, something which is strongly related to the "true" blood demand?

Comment: You need to tell us more, maybe showing some plots (the time series). Do the series sometimes rise so high that you are sure it reaches (or above) the true demand?

Comment: @user2974951, There are certain periods during which the annual blood usage accurately reflects the "true demand", meaning, the blood supply has been plentiful enough that there was no need to restrict its release. This assumption is based on the data for the "mean blood reserve (day)," which is calculated by dividing the total amount of blood reserve by the average daily blood usage. If the "mean blood reserve (day)" did not fall below 5 days at any point within a single year, I can conclude that the blood release was unrestricted, and the blood usage accurately reflected the "true" demand.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, currently, I do not have any plots available as I am still in the data acquisition stage. Regarding your question, the "mean blood reserve (day)" I mentioned above is a crucial factor in estimating the discrepancy between the "apparent" (observed annual blood usage) and the "true" blood demand. It is commonly accepted that the blood release does not need to be restricted when the "mean blood reserve (day)" reaches 5 days. Typically, this value remains between 2 to 5 days. If it falls below 2 days, blood release would be heavilly resctriced to preserve blood for ER patients.